# CK Editor cannot set toolbar location (react js)

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to put the toolbar in bottom of my editor. As per the docs I have passed toolbarPosition:bottom property to config but seems like it didn't work. Here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
        onInit={editor => {
          // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
          console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
        }}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          const data = editor.getData();
          console.log({ event, editor, data });
        }}
        config={{
          toolbarLocation: 'bottom'
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but still the toolbar was placed on top
[image]

Any help would be really thankfull.

Comment: `toolbarLocation` config is [not supported any more](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/migrate.html) for `>= 5` CKEditor. You can customize the toolbar and its position by using a [decoupled editor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-decoupled_decouplededitor-DecoupledEditor.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use decoupled editor as mentioned in the comment and in closed [issue 8168](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8168). You can find working example on this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-https-4hvq2).

Basically, you want to place toolbar **append** toolbar to container of editor component:

```
import React from "react";
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import DecoupledcEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CKEditor
        editor={DecoupledcEditor}
        data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
        onInit={(editor) => {
          console.log("Editor is ready to use!");
          console.log(editor.ui.getEditableElement());
          editor.ui
            .getEditableElement()
            .parentElement.append(editor.ui.view.toolbar.element);
        }}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          const data = editor.getData();
          console.log({ event, editor, data });
        }}
        config={{
          toolbarLocation: "bottom"
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Follow [official guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html#using-create-react-app1) for more information.